# Перенос проекта на Flask

Tags: python, flask

Всем привет!
На локалке у меня есть проект на flask с разными установленными пакетами.

Сейчас хочу перенести это все на vps, но возник вопрос как правильно это сделать? Установить в папке домена flask и после перезаписать файлы? Или есть более правильные способы?
Спасибо!

Comment: Что мешает установить эти пакеты с нуля на VPS?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/

Comment: Так ничего не мешает, я и говорю насколько я правильно решил сделать перенос? С ваших слов, я должен все установить с нуля и после уже перезаписать файлы? За ссылку спасибо!

Comment: Установи самым простым способом как-будто фласк приложение единственное что там будет, дальше уже поймешь стоит ли его упаковывать/деплоить по иному.